# Adding images into the iPhone application

Tags: iphone, camera

I have an application where the user should be able to take pictures using camera and save them within the application. By default all the images taken are saved to the photo album.But I want to bring them into my project just like the way we add required images for the project into the Resources folder in Xcode. At the same time I want them  to converted into PNG format.

Comment: did not get your question, do you want to create a project which takes pictures from camera and need to store into documents folder of application?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation for the camera? All your question are answered if you read it. Also you can't import image into the resource directory of you app. since the images there are copied in to the app bundle which isn't writeable. You should save them in the document directory.

Comment: @jignesh yes i want to do the same. Help me please

Comment: you can take a look at UIImagePickerController, it has delegate methods where you will get image taken from camera

Comment: are u planning to keep connected your iphone with pc or what ???

Comment: @Jignesh Yes I have taken the picture using delegate methods. Now i need to save it. Dunno how to achieve it. Please explain me

Comment: @Maulik No, no such idea

Comment: @Deepak, I have added answer to store image in documents path, check it...

Comment: @Jignesh One more clarification. Actually what is this documents directory ? and where it resides in the project ?

Comment: Still you are confusing, There is a difference between application and project, so please specify, do you want to have image in project or inside application?

Comment: @Jignesh 
I am sorry i am a newbie. Indeed i dunno the difference between those two. I thought both are same. Can u pls tel me the diff and also how to save the image in each context ?

Comment: Each application that runs have its own Documents Directory where you can store the application related stuff, i:e Database files, images, video files, audio files etc. And these can also be fetched again from that Documents Directory for further usage.

Comment: @iphonePlayer OK thank you for the explanation. Exactly that is where i want 2 save the images. And btw where should i implement the code u have given. How can i get that image which you have mentioned as imageFromCamera ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a great tutorial that you should check out http://iosdevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html

And here is the documentation from Apple for the UIImagePickerController that you should use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Answer (score 1):

After you have taken image from Camera you can save this image to your application's document directory as,

```
UIImage *image = imageFromCamera;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage.png"];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

Its tested code and working absolutely fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Where i should write this code in imagepickercontroller delegate methods ?

Comment: implement the above code in this delegate method and replace 'imageFromCamera' with 'image' that is the argument of the described delegate method..  '- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo'

Comment: @iphonePlayer I couldnt find the saved file ?? Where it is being saved ?

Comment: home->Library->Application Support-> iPhone Simulator->4.2->Applications->(Find your application)->Documents->MyImage.png

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *UsrDocPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *DocsDir = [UsrDocPath objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [DocsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.jpg"];

//Check if image exists on documents path, if exists removed it, but it depends on your logic, you can add more images in documents path by changing its name...
    BOOL success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:zipPath];

    if(success){
        [FileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }

    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```